# Why does "lay's" turn into "layaposs"?

Tags: ruby, string, unicode, character-encoding

I'm playing with an ecommerce website for my local supermarket.

When filtering products on the brand "Lay's", the url shows it as "layaposs". This should get normalized to simply "lays".

I'm wondering why this happens and how do I reproduce it with Ruby?

Comment: It would help if you'd show examples of the actual URLs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like there are two filters that turned it that way:

1. lay's => lay&apos;s (this is turning the ' into its XML entity, `&apos;`). Other entities include `&amp;` for &, `&lt;` for <, `&gt;` for >, and `&quot;` for ".
2. stripping out all non-alphabetic characters, leaving you with layaposs.

I've once had a site turn my last name into Jesteroemminusy. Seriously, no kidding. Basically, the hyphen in my last name got turned into "oemminus", and then the rest of my last name, after the Y, got truncated.

Comment: Lol, that's funny. Thanks for the answer.